# Bash: convert local time to UTC during the DST end

Tags: bash, date, utc, date-formatting

Probably asked (many times) before but cannot find anything helpful.

I have a csv file with timeseries. Dates are local without indicating timezone or DST. I use  bash and date utility to convert all dates in the file to UTC. However, during the DST end in October there are two identical timestamps with different meaning. How to handle this, e.g. is there any argument to date command to indicate that the original local date is before/after DST end?

Here is the command I use to convert (in the loop, date is stored in variable):

```bash
date -u -Iseconds --date='TZ="Europe/Rome" 2021-10-31T01:55:00'
```

```
2021-10-31T01:55:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-30T23:55:00+00:00, OK
2021-10-31T01:56:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-30T23:56:00+00:00, OK
2021-10-31T01:57:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-30T23:57:00+00:00, OK
2021-10-31T01:58:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-30T23:58:00+00:00, OK
2021-10-31T01:59:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-30T23:59:00+00:00, OK
2021-10-31T02:00:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:00:00+00:00, wrong
2021-10-31T02:01:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:01:00+00:00, wrong
2021-10-31T02:02:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:02:00+00:00, wrong
2021-10-31T02:03:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:03:00+00:00, wrong
2021-10-31T02:04:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:04:00+00:00, wrong
2021-10-31T02:05:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:05:00+00:00, wrong
...
2021-10-31T02:55:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:55:00+00:00, wrong
2021-10-31T02:56:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:56:00+00:00, wrong
2021-10-31T02:57:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:57:00+00:00, wrong
2021-10-31T02:58:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:58:00+00:00, wrong
2021-10-31T02:59:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:59:00+00:00, wrong
2021-10-31T02:00:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:00:00+00:00, OK
2021-10-31T02:01:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:01:00+00:00, OK
2021-10-31T02:02:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:02:00+00:00, OK
2021-10-31T02:03:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:03:00+00:00, OK
2021-10-31T02:04:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:04:00+00:00, OK
2021-10-31T02:05:00,values  # converts to 2021-10-31T01:05:00+00:00, OK
...
```

EDITED (as requested)

Input file:

```
2021-10-31T01:45:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T02:00:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T02:15:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T02:30:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T02:45:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T02:00:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T02:15:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T02:30:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T02:45:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T03:00:00,value1,value2
```

Output file:

```
2021-10-30T23:45:00+00:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T00:00:00+00:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T00:15:00+00:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T00:30:00+00:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T00:45:00+00:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T01:00:00+00:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T01:15:00+00:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T01:30:00+00:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T01:45:00+00:00,value1,value2
2021-10-31T02:00:00+00:00,value1,value2
```

How the script will know if 2021-10-31T02:15:00 in input file is CET or CEST. Obviously by position in the file, first occurence is CEST and the second one is CET. Ha, this is easy to explain but complex to implement in bash, and all this because someone used local time without timezone in the csv file.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk, I manually edited output and introduced the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is:

> is there any argument to date command to indicate that the original local date is before/after DST end?

Yes, you add the timezone. In this case: `CET` from Central European Time or `CEST` from Central Eastern European Time.

```
$ date -u -Iseconds --date 'TZ="Europe/Rome" 2021-10-31T02:59:00 CET'
2021-10-31T01:59:00+00:00
$ date -u -Iseconds --date 'TZ="Europe/Rome" 2021-10-31T02:59:00 CEST'
2021-10-31T00:59:00+00:00
```

Comment: Nice. Now, it seems to me that there are zone pairs for whole Europe, i.e. CET/CEST for the main part, EET/EEST for Baltic, GMT/BST for UK. Moreover, when adding timezone then prefix defining the country/city is ignored and can be removed.

Comment: `Moreover, when adding timezone then prefix defining the country/city is ignored and can be removed` I do not think so. Different countries have had different timezones at different times. Some combinations may be not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it in shell with [date](/questions/tagged/date)

```bash
zone='Europe/Paris'
while IFS=, read -r localDate rest; do 
  epoch=$(TZ="$zone" date -d "$localDate" '+%s')
  utcDate=$(date --utc -d "@$epoch" -Iseconds)
  printf '%s,%s\n' "$utcDate" "$rest"
done < input.file
```

But I'd rather do it in a language that can convert a timestamp between time zones a little more elegantly

Here's [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) (keep your "elegantly" comments to yourself...)

```bash
perl -MDateTime -MDateTime::Format::ISO8601 -F, -ane '
    $F[0] = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime($F[0])
                ->set_time_zone("Europe/Paris")
                ->set_time_zone("UTC");
    print join ",", @F
' input.file
```

or, not as a one-liner:

```perl
#!perl
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;
use autodie;

my $parser = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->new;
my $file = shift @ARGV;
open my $fh, '<', $file;
while (<$fh>) {
    my ($timestamp, $rest) = split /,/, $_, 2;
    my $utc_date = $parser->parse_datetime($timestamp)
                          ->set_time_zone('Europe/Paris')
                          ->set_time_zone('UTC');
    printf '%s,%s', $parser->format_datetime($utc_date), $rest;
}
close $fh;
```

```bash
perl convert.pl input.file
```

```
2021-10-30T23:45:00Z,value1,value2
2021-10-31T01:00:00Z,value1,value2
2021-10-31T01:15:00Z,value1,value2
...
```